# Static Object of a class in another class in aggregation relationship C++

Tags: oop, c++11, static, aggregation

I have two classes first class contains the object of another class as static but C++ doesnot allow me to do this and gives me some error.

source.cpp

```
#include"control.h"

int main()
{
  Controller cnt;
  cnt.tempcont();
  return 0;
}
```

control.h

```
#include"recorder.h"

class Controller 
{
public:
  static recorder rec;
  void tempcont();
};

recorder Controller::rec;
```

control.cpp

```
#include"control.h"

void Controller::tempcont()
{
  rec.temprec();
}
```

recorder.h

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class recorder
{
public:
  int a;
  void temprec();
};
```

recorder.cpp

```
#include"recorder.h"

void recorder::temprec()
{
  cout << "temp rec called";
}
```

I am getting the following errors and i have no idea why these errors are comming..

Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found

Error   LNK2005 "public: static class recorder Controller::rec" (?rec@Controller@@2Vrecorder@@A) already defined in control.obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the variable `Controller::rec` in the header file. That means the variable will be defined in every [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where that header file have been included. It should only be defined in *one single* translation unit.

This is very easy to do: Just move the definition to a *single* source file.